# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o681.saveAsTable. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to create a user defined table using PySpark But the code is failing with the following error.

File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.4.4/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 778, in saveAsTable
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.4.4/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in **call**
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.4.4/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.4.4/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o681.saveAsTable.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:200)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeAndRead(DataSource.scala:503)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.saveDataIntoTable(createDataSourceTables.scala:217)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:176)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:678)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:678)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:678)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.createTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:474)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:453)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:409)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ResultStage 30 (saveAsTable at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for task.  at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:554)    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:485)     at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:64)  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage4.sort_addToSorter_0$(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage4.processNext(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RowIteratorFromScala.advanceNext(RowIterator.scala:83)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinScanner.advancedBufferedToRowWithNullFreeJoinKey(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:811)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinScanner.(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:686)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:213)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:150)   at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$$res$1(Executor.scala:412)  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:419)  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1359)    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:430)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for task.    at org.spark_project.guava.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)   at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient.sendRpcSync(TransportClient.java:263)    at org.apache.spark.network.sasl.SaslClientBootstrap.doBootstrap(SaslClientBootstrap.java:70)   at org.apache.spark.network.crypto.AuthClientBootstrap.doSaslAuth(AuthClientBootstrap.java:115)     at org.apache.spark.network.crypto.AuthClientBootstrap.doBootstrap(AuthClientBootstrap.java:74)     at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:257)     at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)     at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleClient.lambda$fetchBlocks$0(ExternalShuffleClient.java:100)  at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:141)     at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.start(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:121)   at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleClient.fetchBlocks(ExternalShuffleClient.java:109)   at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.sendRequest(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:260)  at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.org$apache$spark$storage$ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator$$send$1(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:531)     at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.fetchUpToMaxBytes(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:526)    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:489)     ... 31 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for task.     at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:276)     at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:96)   at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient.sendRpcSync(TransportClient.java:259)    ... 44 more
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1493)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2107)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2079)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
... 35 more

Error %!(EXTRA *exec.ExitError=exit status 1)

The table creation occasionally fails, but I could not understand the reason for it.